# Problem with Sqlite3 when doing a Bundle Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I'm really having a hard time solving this since I don't see any possible solutions that is already written on the net, So I decided to ask a question here at StackOverflow.

Firstly, I have created a new Rails app called "MicroTwitter":

```
rails new MicroTwitter -T
```

Here the -T option to the rails command tells Rails not to generate a test directory
associated with the default Test::Unit framework.

After that, I added a few lines on the Gemfile:

```
group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
    gem 'rspec'
    gem 'webrat'
end
```

And so I did a `bundle install`

But after minutes of waiting, It was stuck up.

```
C:\Users\MDF\Desktop\apps\rails apps\MicroTwitter>bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.8.7)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.5)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.5.0)
Using activemodel (3.0.5)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.2)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.26)
Using actionpack (3.0.5)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.1)
Using treetop (1.4.9)
Using mail (2.2.15)
Using actionmailer (3.0.5)
Using arel (2.0.9)
Using activerecord (3.0.5)
Using activeresource (3.0.5)
Using bundler (1.0.11)
Using diff-lcs (1.1.2)
Using nokogiri (1.4.4.1)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.5)
Using rails (3.0.5)
Using rspec-core (2.5.1)
Using rspec-expectations (2.5.0)
Using rspec-mocks (2.5.0)
Using rspec (2.5.0)
Using rspec-rails (2.5.0)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.3)
```

It stuck up just to **sqlite3**. To those who knew how to solve this problem, Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to gem install sqlite3 on your machine via `gem install sqlite3`? Did you have the same problem?

Comment: Yes, I have installed sqlite3 using "gem install sqlite3"

Comment: Which version of bundler are you using?

Comment: I have checked using the "bundle -v" command and it turns out that the version is 1.0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out the problem.
I for got to install the "webrat" gem.

After I installed webrat:

```
gem install webrat
```

and did a bundle install again, It works like magic!
I guess I have to be more careful next time. Thank you for all the answers and comments! :)